# how to handle possibly undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript, undefined

I'm having a problem with TS2322 error:

> Type (string | undefined)[] is not assignable to type string[]

This is my code:

```
 const keys: string[] = objectList
      .map(obj => obj.Key)
      .filter(key => { return !!key;});
```

where Key is an optional parameter of the its class (S3.Types.ObjectList for full disclosure).

I'm 100% sure that there is no undefined element in keys as i'm removing them with my filter.

How would you do do to remove this error ?

Regards,
Julien

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Typescript does not flow checking information from `filter` in any way, so the only thing we can do is use a not null assertion:

```
const keys: string[] = objectList
  .map(obj => obj.Key!) // ! means we know this is not null, we won't actually know until the next check 
  .filter(key => !!key);
```

Or a more consistent version where we assert only after the check:

```
const keys: string[] = objectList
  .filter(obj => !!obj.Key)
  .map(obj => obj.Key!)
```

Comment: I didn't know about that new feature, it's brilliant. Thanks a lot.